# Read line by line between a pattern, then print in de-limited format

Tags: linux, awk

I have a ascii file with the contents given below:

```
START
this is my home
this is my pc

START
this is my linux
this is my awk
this is nice

START
this is a single line

START
this is my work
this is the end
this line has to be read

START
...
...

START
.
.
.
.
```

I want to read the lines between START and the blank line and print the output in delimited format.
output should be the below format:

```
this is my home;this is my pc
this is my linux;this is my awk;this is nice
this is a single line
this is my work;this is the end;this line has to be read
```

I have used semicolon as delimiter.
Please note: number of lines between START and Blank line is not fixed.

I have tried using awk, but I am able to read only one line after START

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "START" } ; { print $1 }'
```

Can anyone guide me to the correct forum/right direction...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
awk -v RS="" '{$1=$1}1' file
START this is my home this is my pc
START this is my linux this is my awk this is nice
START this is a single line
START this is my work this is the end this line has to be read
```

To make sure each section contains `START` and remove it:

```
awk -v RS="" '{$1=$1} /^START/ {gsub(/^START /,"");print}' file
this is my home this is my pc
this is my linux this is my awk this is nice
this is a single line
this is my work this is the end this line has to be read
```

---

To give you some additional information on why your `awk` did fail.
You need to reconstruct every line after changing the RS, by using `$1=$1`
Then print the whole line by `1` or `{print $0}`
So to make your `awk`to work:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "START" } {$1=$1} 1' file
```

or like this

```
awk -v RS="START" '{$1=$1} NR>1' file
```

The `NR>1` prevents the first blank line form being printer.

The multiple characters in RS, makes this less portable, and you need  `gnu awk`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{$1=$1} sub(/^START /,"")' file
this is my home this is my pc
this is my linux this is my awk this is nice
this is a single line
this is my work this is the end this line has to be read
```

Answer (score 0):

This builds a single string containing relevant parts of the input file with the blocks separated by '\n' and the lines separated by ';'.

```
awk '
  t && $0 == "" { t = 0 ; sep = "\n" }
  t             { hold = hold sep $0 ; sep = ";" }
  $0 == "START" { t = 1 }
  END           { print hold }
' file
```

The first line deals with the end of a block.

If the in-a-block trigger is set, the second line appends a separator (either "", "\n" or ";" as appropriate) and the current record to the hold buffer.

The third line sets the trigger when a block starts -- if a block has already been started, the "START" line will be treated as part of the block.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't preserve the individual lines in each block of lines as separate fields, to be separated with `;` in the output; the following does:

```
awk -v RS='' -F'\n' -v OFS=';' '{sub(/^START\n/,""); $1=$1; print }' file
```

- `RS=''` (setting the input record separator `RS` to an empty string) is an `awk` *idiom* with special meaning: it breaks the input into *blocks* of lines based on empty lines as the separators; in other words: each block of contiguous, non-empty lines forms *one* record.
- `-F'\n'` sets the *input* field separator (also accessible as special variable `FS`) to a newline, so that *each line* in each record (block of lines) will become its own *field*.
- `OFS=';'` sets the *output* field separator to `;`, as requested by the OP.
- `sub(/^START\n/,"")` strips the `START` line (plus its trailing newline) from each record (block of lines).
- `$1=$1` is a trick that, by assigning to a field variable, causes the input record to be *rebuilt* from its individual fields using the value of `OFS` as the separator; here, the individual lines (without their trailing newline) - are effectively joined with `;` to form a *single* line.
- `print` simply outputs the rebuilt record.